# Jquery Code Simplification

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I'm rather new to jQuery and I'm trying to figure out a way to simplify/optimize my code, because right now it works but I just know there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
$(".th_s3studios_layout").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    // Fading in the project page
    $("#th_s3studios_layout").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
$(".th_mangafan_layout").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    // Fading in the project page
    $("#th_mangafan_layout").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
$(".th_356_P3").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    // Fading in the project page
    $("#th_356_P3").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
$(".th_hrycyna_layout").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    // Fading in the project page
    $("#th_hrycyna_layout").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Here is some corresponding HTML markup that goes with it.

```
    <div class="col_16" id="portfolio_home">
        <div class="col_04 folio"><div class="th_s3studios_layout">Content 1</div></div>
        <div class="col_04 folio"><div class="th_mangafan_layout">Content 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col_16" id="th_s3studios_layout"
        <div class="col_04 folio"><div class="preview1">Pop up stuff for content 1</div></div>
        <div class="col_04 folio"><div class="preview2">Pop up stuff for content 1</div></div>
    </div
    <div class="col_16" id="th_mangafan_layout"
        <div class="col_04 folio"><div class="preview1">Pop up stuff for content 2</div></div>
        <div class="col_04 folio"><div class="preview2">Pop up stuff for content 2</div></div>
    </div
```

You can see the function basically fades out one box and fades in another. You can see that the box it fades in is always the same name as the .click function, except it's a separate CSS id container and not a class. I figure there must be a way to create a shared function for each of these that somehow changes the the name of the class to an id matching the same name of the function, and re-uses the rest of the code. Can anyone help me shed some light on this?

Comment: It's very difficult to provide any suggestion without seeing the structure of your HTML. I suggest you have a look at jQuery traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: I added the HTML markup to help clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(".th_s3studios_layout,.th_mangafan_layout,.th_356_P3,.th_hrycyna_layout").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    var newId="#"+ $(this).attr('class').replace(".","");
    $(newId).delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: I just tested it and it seemed to work just the same as my separate functions did. So thanks a lot for everyone's help, I think this is basically exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation yet to do that. I will eventually!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML or modifying your HTML, this is one way to do it that works even if your clicked on items have more than one class name on them:

```
var classList = [
    ".th_s3studios_layout", 
    ".th_mangafan_layout",
    ".th_356_P3",
    ".th_hrycyna_layout"
];

$(classList.join(",")).click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    var this$ = $(this);
    // find which class name is in the clicked on item
    for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
        if (this$.hasClass(classList[i]) {
            $("#" + classList[i].substr(1))..delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

If we could see your HTML and add classes to your HTML, it could be done even simpler.

For example, if you only have one class on the clicked objects, it could be done like this:

```
$($(".th_s3studios_layout, .th_mangafan_layout, .th_356_P3, .th_hrycyna_layout").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    $("#" + this.className).delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple classes, and if your element (div for example) is like that :

```
<div id="th_s3studios_layout" class="th_s3studios_layout"></div>
```

No need to name the class with the same as the id.

Do something like that :

```
<a id="th_s3studios_layout" class="fader">See content</a>
<div id="target_th_s3studios_layout">Content</div>
<a id="th_mangafan_layout" class="fader">See content</a>
<div id="target_th_mangafan_layout">Content</div>
...

$(".fader").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio_home").fadeOut(500);
    var id='#target_'+$(this).attr('id');
    $(id).delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this JS:

```
$(".whateveryouwanthere").click(function(){
    $("#adjustthis").fadeOut(500);
    // Fading in the project page
    $("#adjustthis").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

And add another class to your elements, for example for `th_s3studios_layout`:

```
<div class="th_s3studios_layout whateveryouwanthere"></div>
```